# Importing NDepend results into SonarQube?

Tags: c#, sonarqube, ndepend

How can I run [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com) from [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/), or import NDepend results into SonarQube?

The SonarQube [C# Ecosystem Plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C#+Ecosystem) supports several other C# tools, but NDepend is not one of them. Commercial and free solutions are both welcome.

If no solution is available yet, can the [NDepend API](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html) be used to write a custom plugin SonarQube with reasonable effort?

---

**Update 2014-12-11:** There was an [announcement](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/sonarqube-integration-ndepend) by the NDepend team today that a SonarQube integration is being developed. It is expected for Q2 2015. They also mention that there is a new third-party [SonarQube plugin](https://github.com/criteo/sonar-ndepend) for importing NDepend results now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am representing the NDepend team. Having a NDepend plugin for SonarQube is certainly a good idea and something we'd like to offer out-of-the-box in future features for NDepend vNext. It is also an idea ranked on the [NDepend User Voice](https://ndepend.uservoice.com/forums/226344-ndepend-user-voice/suggestions/4558335-provide-a-sonarqube-plugin).

Please come back to us by email at *support at ndepend dot com*. We'd like to hear the details of your needs concerning *import NDepend results into SonarQube*.

For now writing your own plugin using NDepend.API is the way to go if you cannot wait. 100% of data collected by NDepend (structure, metrics, diff, trend...) are reachable through the API. The NDepend PowerTools source code is the right place to get started with NDepend API and see how main API usage scenarios can be implemented.

Comment: Is there an easy way to access the NDepend.API from Java (which SonarQube plugins are written) currently? Seems like it would be easier to execute NDepend and save the results to a file which is then parsed by the SonarQube plugin.  This is the approach taken for most of the .net plugins in SonarQube, such as FxCop, StyleCop and my ReSharper plugin

Comment: NDepend.API is pure .NET, there is no easy way to access it from  Java. Saving to a file is certainly a solution, but the read/write overhead makes it far from optimal. Thanks for your detailed answer below John, SonarQube .Net ReSharper Plugins will certainly represent a great inspiration for our integration job.

Comment: If the integration worked only by reading the NDepend results from a file, that would still be great! In fact, that is what some other SonarQube components do, and it's perfectly OK. So, before delaying the plugin project because of a lack of a more elegant solution, go for it and rather try to import as much data as you can. Thanks Patrick and John for your excellent and insightful answers.

Answer (score 1):

While I was writing the [SonarQube .Net ReSharper plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/232359533), I looked at the potential for an NDepend plugin.  The biggest obstacle is that SonarQube requires plugins to provide the *full* list of possible violations (rules) at server start, which must then be manually enabled by administrators via the web UI (ie: **not** through an API).  There is no API for adding or enabling rules via the SonarQube API during plugin execution.

Once the rules are in there, it's just an excersize in associating the NDepend results with the source code lines/files. The [.Net ecosystem plugins](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-dotnet), as well as my [ReSharper plugin](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-dotnet-resharper), are all open source and can be used for inspiration on this point.

Since a lot of NDepend's power comes from the ability to easily create your own rules, a plugin author would have to create some mechanism for getting those custom rules into SonarQube without having to frequently restart the SonarQube servers. So far, no one has taken the time to do this, although it sounds like the NDepend team is considering it based on Patrick's answer to this same question.